# What is Tuya expecting for the time header in API calls?

Tags: php, smartthings, tuya

I'm trying to interact with the Tuya API from a PHP webapp.

I have authenticated the user and now have the code which is returned from Tuya. I now need to submit that via the [Authorisation Management](https://docs.tuya.com/en/iot/open-api/api-list/api/oauth-management?id=K95ztzpoll7v5) API to get an authorisation for subsequent API requests.

Following is the code I'm using to make the request to the Authorsiation Management API:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://openapi.tuyaeu.com/v1.0/token?grant_type=2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('client_id: MY_TUYA_CLIENT_ID', 't: ' . time(), 'code' . $_GET['code']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

No matter what I try, the error I receive is always error code 1013 "request time is invalid".

I believe the parameters need to be passed in the header, hence why I'm using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to pass each of the values, but I suspect that is not correct.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time() * 1000`

They need 13 character timestamp.